# How to center grid besides label?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to accomplish the following layout:

[image]

I am stuck in this however:

[image]

I am using Bootstrap. Here's my html code:

```
<div class="metrics-group">
          <p>Revenue</p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="6month_old_revenue">6 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="5month_old_revenue">5 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="5month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="4month_old_revenue">4 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="4month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row traction-row>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="3month_old_revenue">3 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="3month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="2month_old_revenue">2 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="2month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="1month_old_revenue">1 month ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="1month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve the first's picture layout?

Comment: What;s the form-group contained in? Can you post all of the relevant code?

Comment: Did it @ZimSystem

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3">
            <p>Revenue (R$)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="6month_old_revenue">6 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="5month_old_revenue">5 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="5month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="4month_old_revenue">4 months ago</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="4month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row traction-row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <label for="3month_old_revenue">3 months ago</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="3month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <label for="2month_old_revenue">2 months ago</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="2month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <label for="1month_old_revenue">1 month ago</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="1month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
              </div>
            </div><!--close inner row -->
    
          </div> <!--close col-9 -->
        </div> <!--close row -->
     </div> <!--close form-group -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the required code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='row'>
  <p class='col-xs-2' style='text-align: center;'><br/><br/><br/>Revenue (R$)</p>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-10">
    <div class='col-xs-4'>
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label for="6month_old_revenue">6 months ago</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label for="6month_old_revenue">5 months ago</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
       </div>
     </div>
     
    <div class='col-xs-4'>
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label for="6month_old_revenue">4 months ago</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label for="6month_old_revenue">3 months ago</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div class='col-xs-4'>
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label for="6month_old_revenue">2 months ago</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label for="6month_old_revenue">1 months ago</label>
           <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use a `row` with two columns

Use a `row` with two columns: one for the `revenue` paragraph and one for the input groups. Use the following classes for the `revenue` paragraph to align it in the center of its container.

1. **`d-flex`** - to change its `display` property to `flex`
2. **`align-items-center`** - to align it vertically in the center of its container
3. **`justify-content-center`** - to align it horizontally in the center of its container.

If you want to center it vertically only on `sm` screens, use `align-items-sm-center`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container metrics-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <p>Revenue</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <label for="6month_old_revenue">6 months ago</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="6month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <label for="5month_old_revenue">5 months ago</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="5month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <label for="4month_old_revenue">4 months ago</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="4month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row traction-row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <label for="3month_old_revenue">3 months ago</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="3month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <label for="2month_old_revenue">2 months ago</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="2month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <label for="1month_old_revenue">1 month ago</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="1month_old_revenue" maxlength="2" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you see in the code I have removed the `form-group` container. It is because `form-group` only adds a `margin-bottom`, nothing more. It is best that you use `form-group` class name for the input columns, because it is good that there is some margin at the bottom of the inputs.

#### Update

As of now, there are two columns on all kinds of devices. Use `col-*` classes that fits your design instead of `col-4` and `col`